# If I patch the disk version of Bloodborne, how can I remove the patch?

Tags: bloodborne

Bloodborne's post-release patches add several balance changes and decrease load times. However, I'd like to learn to speedrun the game, and the fastest possible speedrun route requires two glitches that were fixed in later patches. So if I apply the patch for its benefits, can I remove it at will for the sake of speedrunning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to remove a patch is to delete the entire game then do a fresh install from the disk.

You will then have to either manually stop the patches from downloading, possibly every time you start your PS4, or disconnect from the internet completely.

I would make a back up of your save files, uninstalling the game should not delete your saves but better to be safe than sorry.

Also your current save files may not be compatible with the un-patched version of the game, so you may have to install the current patch to use your existing saves. This is the case with certain games but I am not sure if it applies to Bloodborne.

I doubt this would be possible with a digital copy of the game as it will always download the fully patched version.

Comment: Just for reference, network access has always been disabled on my PS4, but my game appears to be patched regardless. I removed the disc, uninstalled Bloodborne, and re-inserted it. My saves were gone, but the patch remained.

Comment: Are you using the 'Game of the Year' edition? it may be already patched on the disk, in which case you are not able to install the original version of the game. Depending on how much you want to do this you could pick up a second hand copy of the original disk to obtain the unpatched version.

Comment: I'm not using the 'Game of the Year' edition as far as I can tell. My cover looks like [this](http://thefreecheese.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/bloodborne-box-art.jpg), except that I bought it in Canada, so there's a French version of most of the text.

Comment: I have a original version of Bloodborne at home that isn't currently installed on my PS4. I will install it when I get home an see what version it is.

Comment: I tested this myself and I can confirm that when I installed from the disk in to my new PS4 pro, (which has never had Bloodborne on it) it was version 1.00. I then downloaded the current 1.09 patch, which was ~9Gb, and installed it. I then deleted the game and then I reinstalled it from the disk and it was back to version 1.00.

Comment: Are you sure you deleted the actual game files and not the save files? You should hit options on the game tile in the XMB and then select 'delete'. You can also check the version of the game you have by selecting 'information' from the same menu.

Comment: It seems I made a mistake replicating the dupe glitch. All is well now thanks to your advice.

Comment: No problem, glad you got there in the end.

Comment: You can’t load a 1.09 save file if you unpatched. (Tested)